# Uniform Continuity exercise

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples, uniform-continuity

I am stuck at this example because I cannot figure out from where comes delta over 2. How can x´be 1/delta. Sorry for the terminologies. Thanks for reading.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of uniform continuity of $g$:

$$\forall \varepsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0: \forall x,x' \in (-\infty ,+\infty) : ( |x -x'| < \delta ) \rightarrow |g(x) - g(x')| < \varepsilon$$

So the negation (by pure logic, and knowing that an implication is false iff the antecedent is true and the conclusion false:

$g$ is **not** uniformly  continuous iff

$$\exists \varepsilon > 0 \forall \delta > 0: \exists x,x' \in (-\infty ,+\infty) : ( |x -x'| < \delta ) \land (|g(x) - g(x')| \ge \varepsilon)$$

This is what the quoted proof does: it chooses $\varepsilon= 1$ and for any $\delta> 0$, the constructed points $x, x'$ indeed satisfy $|x -x'| = \frac{\delta}{2} < \delta$ and $|g(x) - g(x') | \ge 1$, as required.

Comment: I will also write, for **not** uniformly continuous, $|g(x)-g(x')| \ge \epsilon$. But I found people simplify it to $|g(x)-g(x')| \gt \epsilon$.

Comment: @N1ng It's a bit stronger but not needed for the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Well  x' is not equals to 1/delta it is assumed to be greater than there so as to  get the contradiction

Answer (score 1):

The definition of uniform continuity says that for any $\epsilon>0$  there is some $\delta$ such that for every pair of points $x,x'$   within $\delta$  of each other, $|g(x)-g(x')|<\epsilon$.

SInce that last $<$ is awkward, they pick a number $\delta/2$ which is assuredley less than $\delta$, and work with that.